# Python: How do I include a function in another function?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, include

I'm just starting to study programming and I have a question about functions. I defined the function leapyear as follows:

```
def leapyear(n):
  # Given a year, decide if it is a leap year or not.
  if n%4==0:
    if n%100==0:
      if n%400==0:
        return "It is a leap year."
      else:
        return "It is not a leap year"
    else:
      return "It is a leap year"
  else:
    return "It is not a leap year"
```

Now I want to use it in another function, which is going to tell me if I wrote a valid date or not (for example, 02/28/2021 is valid, but 02/29/2021 is not). What I did is this:

```
def valid_date():
  day = int(input("Day: "))
  month = input("Month: ")
  year = int(input("Year: "))
  
  if month=="January":
    if day<=31:
      print("Valid date")
    else:
      print("Not a valid date")

  if month=="February":
    if year%4==0:
      if year%100==0:
        if year%400==0:
          if day<=29:
            print("Valid date")
          else:
            print("Not a valid date")
        else:
          if day<=28:
            print("Valid date")
          else:
            print("Not a valid date")
      else:
        if day<=29:
          print("Valid date")
        else:
          print("Not a valid date")
    else:
      if day<=28:
        print("Fecha válida")
      else:
        print("Fecha no válida")

  if month=="March":
    if day<=31:
      print("Valid date")
    else:
      print("Not a valid date")
```

It actually gets to December, but it doesn't really matter because it is basically the same.

The code works, ***but I was thinking to use the leapyear function instead of writing the whole code again***. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your function should just return `True` or `False`; let the caller decide if a string representation like `"It's a leap year"` is warranted.

```
def leapyear(n):
  # Given a year, decide if it is a leap year or not.
  if n%4==0:
    if n%100==0:
      if n%400==0:
        return True
      else:
        return False
    else:
      return True
  else:
    return False
```

Inside your `valid_date` function, you can call `leapyear` and use its result to determine if February can have a 29th in that year.

```
def valid_date():
  day = int(input("Day: "))
  month = input("Month: ")
  year = int(input("Year: "))
  
  if month=="January":
    if day<=31:
      print("Valid date")
    else:
      print("Not a valid date")

  if month=="February":
    if leapyear(year):
      last_day = 29
    else:
      last_day = 28
    if day <= last_day:
      print("Valid date")
    else:
      print("Not a valid date")

  if month=="March":
    if day<=31:
      print("Valid date")
    else:
      print("Not a valid date")
```

Comment: Thank you! I only have one question. In the first item, I had to define a function which would return "It is a leap year" or "It is not a leap year". I can do that by writing print("It is /not a leap year"), but I also get the True value. Is there a way to avoid that? I mean, to get the print value, but not the return value.

Comment: One more question. If I do what I wrote on the last comment, the printing "It is a leap year" (or not) also appears in the function valid_date. Is there any way to avoid that?

Comment: You can leave `leapyear` as originally defined, then use `if leapyear(year) == "It is a leap year.":`. Using Boolean values is cleaner: if you know the function is supposed to return a Boolean value, there are only two possible values to worry about. There are an *infinite* number of `str` values that your `leapyear` could return (if if it is only designed to return two of them), leaving lots of room for potential bugs.

Comment: Also note that `valid_date` should return a string (or better yet, a Boolean value), rather than printing a string. Let the caller decide what to do with the string. (In general, try to push I/O "up" as far as possible.)

Comment: (This applies to input as well; `valid_date` should take integers `day`, `month`, and `year` as arguments, letting the caller worry about how to get those values from the user.)

Comment: Great. I think I got it. By the way, the leapyear function didn't have to print anything. It only had to decide if it was or not a leap year. I misread the exercise. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let your fingers be lazy. Shorter programs are generally easier to read.

```
def leapyear( y):
  return (y%4==0 and y%100!=0) or y%400==0

def valid_date( year, month, day):
  if (day <= 0) or (month <= 0) or (year < 1582): return False
  
  last = [31,29 if leapyear( year) else 28,31,30,31,30,31,31,30,31,30,31]
  return (month <= 12) and (day <= last[month-1])

year, month, day = input( "Enter date (yyyy-mm-dd):").split( '-')

if valid_date( int( year), int( month), int( day)): 
  print( "Fecha válida")
else:  print( "Fecha no válida")
```

The leapyear() code is only valid for years starting in 1582 (pope Grégoire). You can add some logic to validate earlier dates.
Your program should also include some validation of user input. For example, alphabetic characters will crash the program.

Comment: Thanks! I thought there was a shorter way, but as I said, I'm new at this and I still A LOT to learn (for example, I didn't know what .split does).

Comment: One question: in line 7 you write 28,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30,31,30. Is that suppose to say how many days are in every month? If so, shouldn't December (the last month) have 31 days?

Comment: @Jorge split() will separate a string in parts. If not specified, the separator will be space but, in this case, it is a dash. You can replace it with a slash. You are right: my 'last' was wrong. I edited the post to fix it.